# Jenkins is replacing text in a build step with other text

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I would not have believed this if I had not seen it with my own eyes. In any sort of build step (we have tried multiple types) the term `http(s)://api.DOMAIN.com` is replaced with `https://licensing.domain.com`.

1. We have verified the behavior on two different computers (one Mac, one Windows 10).
2. Both `licensing.domain.com` and `api.domain.com` are valid domain names. `licensing.domain.com` is used in other jobs.
3. It occurs at the time of saving with any job that we create or edit. If we create a job and add a build step that should print `https://api.domain.com` it prints `https://licensing.domain.com`.
4. It occurs with any type of build step.
5. The text is modified in the configuration of the job build step.
6. The job does not have to be executed. It occurs when it is saved at the time of creation or when it is edited.

`https://api.domain.com => https://licensing.domain.com`

But when we join the protocol (HTTP or HTTPS) to the domain name, we do not experience the issue.

`'https://' + 'api.domain.com' => https://api.domain.com`

Changing the domain extension does not change the string.

`http://api.domain.net => https://api.domain.net`

I was intimately involved in setting up the system and I have not created anything that to my knowledge would cause this to occur.

Comment: Is it changing the value in the saved job (in other words, when you put in `http://api.domain`, click **Save**, then go back to **Configure**, does it now show `http://licensing.domain`?), or is it only changing what is printed out in the console as a result of running the job?

Comment: What type of job are you using, freestyle, pipeline or something else?

Comment: I updated my question. It occurs in both the configuration and the console output. We have only tested it with freestyle jobs.

Comment: I received a correction from a workmate and have edited accordingly.

Comment: Do you have the [Job Configuration History](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jobConfigHistory) plugin? If so, does the job's history show anything incriminating (for example, an entry with your changes, then a subsequent entry by `SYSTEM` that changes `https://api.domain.com` to `https://licensing.domain.com`?

Comment: @bto we do not have that plugin installed.